# Can I have an entire declarative pipeline defined and parameterized in a shared library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

Essentially I want my Jenkinsfile to look something like this:

```
@Library('my-descriptive-pipline') _
myPipeline('arg1','arg2','arg3')
```

Then my shared library (/vars/descriptivePipeline.groovy) would look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
      skipDefaultCheckout()
    }
    environment {
    }
    stages {
        stage('stageA') {
            steps {
                ... Do something with arg1, arg2 or arg3
            }
        }
        stage('stageB') {
            steps {
                ... Do something with arg1, arg2 or arg3
            }
        }
    ....
```

I want to centralize the pipeline config so I don't have to worry about Jenkinsfile sprawl. Is this possible with declarative pipelines?

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?  I am trying to do the exact same thing and it isn't looking good....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entire Pipelines can now be defined in shared libraries as of Declarative Pipeline 1.2.

You can find more [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/) and [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)

Comment: there are limitations though - "Only entire pipelines can be defined in shared libraries as of this time. This can only be done in vars/*.groovy, and only in a call method. Only one Declarative Pipeline can be executed in a single build, and if you attempt to execute a second one, your build will fail as a result." [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines)

Comment: also using `script` blocks inside `steps` don't seem to work.  A workaround is to wrap the `script` block within a function and call the function within `steps`.

Answer (score 4):

As the [shared libraries plugin documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries) states:

> Defining Declarative Pipelines
>
> Starting with Declarative 1.2, released in late September, 2017, you
>   can define Declarative Pipelines in your shared libraries as well.

This is fairly new and so there might still be a few bugs around but it should work. Don't forget to upgrade the shared library and declarative plugins though.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not currently possible to share a complete declarative pipeline. It *is* possible with scripted pipelines:

Begin quote:
"The declarative option is nice but you will lose the ability to extract out reusable code via the shared library.  For example, you can't do this yet:

```
MyCompanyStandardPipeline {
    ... // which will plugin standard sections...
}
```

End quote from Cuong Tran on the [jenkins users mailing list](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Declarative-pipelines-vs-scripted-td4891792.html).

You can use shared libraries with either Jenkinsfile variant, as the next reply on the linked thread points out, but only with scripted can you share a *complete* pipeline.

Comment: can i have post actions in scripted pipelines? i thinks thats only for declarative right?

Comment: the `post` stanza is a declarative thing, but you can do the same thing in a scripted pipeline by just continuing to write more code in the Jenkinsfile. :D

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommend to have entire pipeline in shared library...  Because developer will never know what is happening in behind the scene... Entrie objective of declarative will go away.. I suggest to create a resuable class or script and let developer compose the pipeline